# Method Generics Without Arguments

Tags: java, generics

Let's say I have a method like this:

```
static class Example 
{
    public static <N extends Number> Number getOddBits(N type)
    {
        if (type instanceof Byte) return (byte)0xAA;
        else if (type instanceof Short) return (short)0xAAAA;
        else if (type instanceof Integer) return 0xAAAAAAAA;
        else if (type instanceof Float) return Float.intBitsToFloat(0xAAAAAAAA);
        else if (type instanceof Long) return 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAL;
        else if (type instanceof Double) return Double.longBitsToDouble(0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAL);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

The actual specifics of the method isn't really important. However, to call this method we use:

```
Example.<Float>getOddBits(0f);
```

My question is, is it possible to write such a method **without** conventional parameters. Without overloading, and ultimately without Boxing.

Ideally invoked by:

```
Example.<Byte>getOddBits();
```

Comment: I suppose no because of erasure, but you could get rid of the superflous instance parameter and use a Class object as parameter : `getOddBits(Class<? extends Number> clazz)`. I don't think you can get around boxing as the return type is not enough to create distinct signatures, i.e. `byte getOddBits()` and `int getOddBits()` may be ambigious.

Comment: There might be other options as well. Why do you need to do this? for your example, with basically static values being returned you could just use an enum. If there is something more specific there could be other options as well. For example, if you are converting a Number to another form, you could make a conversion interface like with a toBytes and fromBytes method. then have whatever classes you need implement it. Im not sure if this helps, if not could you give a more specific example closer to what you need it to do?

Comment: @JohnKane The example was arbitrary, just to demonstrate the use of a subclass return type as specified via an argument in the neatest way possible. I probably could have gone with the old `foo-bar-baz`, but I thought that a practical example would be better suited.

Comment: I know, I was just wondering if you had something more specific in mind. If you did it could effect how your question was answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an enhancement to KennyTM's suggestion, you could combine a Class argument with method generics to return the specialised type:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <N extends Number> N getOddBits(Class<N> cls) {
    Number out;
    if (cls == Byte.class) {
        out = (byte)0xAA;
    } else if (cls == Short.class) {
        out = (short)0xAAAA;
    } else if (cls == Integer.class) {
        out = 0xAAAAAAAA;
    } else if (cls == Float.class) {
        out = Float.intBitsToFloat(0xAAAAAAAA);
    } else if (cls == Long.class) {
        out = 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAL;
    } else if (cls == Double.class) {
        out = Double.longBitsToDouble(0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAL);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return (N)out;
}
```

This will allow you to assign the following, and avoid a cast on each invocation:

```
    float result = Example.getOddBits(Float.class);
```

Comment: Just submitted an edit to support primitive values as well (`cls==Integer.class || cls==int.class`). This is definitely the optimal solution from a cleanliness of invocation perspective.

Comment: (That is, `int i = Example.getOddBits(int.class);`)

Answer (score 7):

How about just take a `.class`?

```
public static Number getOddBits(Class<? extends Number> cls)
{
    if (cls == Byte.class) {
        return (byte)0xAA;
    } else if (cls == Short.class) {
        return (short)0xAAAA;
    } else if (cls == Integer.class) {
        return 0xAAAAAAAA;
    } else if (cls == Float.class) {
        return Float.intBitsToFloat(0xAAAAAAAA);
    } else if (cls == Long.class) {
        return 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAL;
    } else if (cls == Double.class) {
        return Double.longBitsToDouble(0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAL);
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}

...

Example.getOddBits(Float.class);
```

Comment: That definitely works. I was really trying to push method generics to the fullest, but I guess erasure makes the use of `Example.<Float>getOddBits()` impossible.

Comment: You can combine this approach with your generic method signature to return a specialised type: `public static <N extends Number> N getOddBits(Class<N> cls) {`

Comment: I've expanded my comment above to a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this will help you, but I have used this in the past for deserializing and returning an Object of the appropriate type.

```
public <T> T deserialize(String xml){
    T object=null;
    ...
    //pull type information from method param
    ...
    return object=(T)type.newInstance(); //helper to instantiate class
}
```

However, I am not entirely sure on what you need to do. A simpler and cleaner way to accomplish this could be to make a Converter interface for the given types that you need and have whatever classes need to use it implement it. Then what ever type you need, could be called directly on the Object itself. for example:

```
inerface Convertor<T>{

    T convert();

    void set(T value);

}





class Something implements Converter<Long,ByteArray>{

    ...

    public ByteArray convert(){...}

    public void set(ByteArray value){...}

}
```